# Combining data from multiple tuples in one bag in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to parse a bunch of log data using pig.  Unfortunately the data for one command is spread across multiple lines (an audit log).  I know that there is an id that correlates all of the log messages and that there are different types that contain pieces of the whole, but I am unsure how to gather them all into one message.

I split the message based on type and then joined based on the id, but since there is a one to many relationship between SYSCALL and PATH, this doesn't gather all of the information on one line.  I can group by id, but then I want to be able to pull out the same field (name) from every PATH tuple but I don't know of anyway to do that.

Should I just write my own UDF?  A FOREACH doesn't keep track of state such that I can concatenate the name field from each tuple.

Edited to add example:

> {"message":"Jan  6 15:30:11 r01sv06 auditd: node=r01sv06 type=SYSCALL
>   msg=audit(1389047402.069:4455727): arch=c000003e syscall=59
>   success=yes exit=0 a0=7fff8ef30600 a1=7fff8ef30630 a2=270f950
>   a3=fffffffffffffff0 items=2 ppid=1493 pid=1685 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0
>   euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=8917
>   comm=\"ip\" exe=\"/sbin/ip\"
>   key=\"command\"","@timestamp":"2014-01-06T22:30:14.642Z","@version":"1","type":"audit","host":"r01sv09a","path":"/data/logs/audit.log","syslog_timestamp":"Jan
>   6 15:30:11","syslog_program":"auditd","received_at":"2014-01-06
>   22:30:14 UTC", "received_from":"r01sv06" ,"syslog_severity_code":5
>   ,"syslog_facility_code":1
>   ,"syslog_facility":"user-level","syslog_severity":"notice","@source_host":"r01sv06"}
>
> {"message":"Jan  6 15:30:11 r01sv06 auditd: node=r01sv06 type=EXECVE
>   msg=audit(1389047402.069:4455727): argc=4 a0=\"/sbin/ip\" a1=\"link\"
>   a2=\"show\"
>   a3=\"lo\"","@timestamp":"2014-01-06T22:30:14.643Z","@version":"1","type":"audit","host":"r01sv09a","path":"/data/logs/audit.log","syslog_timestamp":"Jan
>   6 15:30:11","syslog_program":"auditd","received_at":"2014-01-06
>   22:30:14 UTC", "received_from":"r01sv06", "syslog_severity_code":5,
>   "syslog_facility_code":1,"syslog_facility":"user-level",
>   "syslog_severity":"notice","@source_host":"r01sv06"}
>
> {"message":"Jan  6 15:30:11 r01sv06 auditd: node=r01sv06 type=CWD
>   msg=audit(1389047402.069:4455727): 
>   cwd=\"/root\"","@timestamp":"2014-01-06T22:30:14.644Z","@version":"1","type":"audit","host":"r01sv09a","path":"/data/logs/audit.log","syslog_timestamp":"Jan
>   6 15:30:11","syslog_program":"auditd","received_at":"2014-01-06
>   22:30:14 UTC","received_from":"r01sv06", "syslog_severity_code":5,
>   "syslog_facility_code":1, "syslog_facility":"user-level",
>   "syslog_severity":"notice", "@source_host":"r01sv06"}
>
> {"message":"Jan  6 15:30:11 r01sv06 auditd: node=r01sv06 type=PATH
>   msg=audit(1389047402.069:4455727): item=0 name=\"/sbin/ip\"
>   inode=1703996 dev=08:02 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0
>   rdev=00:00","@timestamp":"2014-01-06T22:30:14.645Z","@version":"1","type":"audit","host":"r01sv09a","path":"/data/logs/audit.log","syslog_timestamp":"Jan
>   6 15:30:11","syslog_program":"auditd","received_at":"2014-01-06
>   22:30:14 UTC", "received_from":"r01sv06", "syslog_severity_code":5,
>   "syslog_facility_code":1,"syslog_facility":"user-level",
>   "syslog_severity":"notice", "@source_host":"r01sv06",}

Comment: Posting some example logs would help people to answer